# Why does Rails save/return the wrong value for a column with a default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using postgressql 9.3.1 and Rails 4.1.4 and are experiencing something strange: a value that is set to false by default is being saved as true!

In `schema.rb`, I have:

```
create_table "practice_scores", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.boolean  "visualized",    default: false
    t.boolean  "selected",      default: false
    ...
end
```

I have:

```
practice_score = PracticeScore.new(assessment: @respondent.assessment, practice: @practice, user: @respondent.user)
@respondent.questions << Question.new(practice: @practice, practice_score: practice_score)
```

I assume this will automatically save `practice_score` when the `Question` is saved and the value of `selected` for practice_score will be `false`. When I examine the object using the rails console, it's `true`.

Is there someway rails maybe overwriting the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird behavior.  Are both records saving?  I believe you need to save before you can use its primary key as a foreign key of another object.  Another option is to use `#create`.

For debugging, use bang methods.  `#save!` or `#create!` The console will blow up in your face with an error if it not valid.

If that doesn't fix the issue, I would do a schema reset.

The command is `rake db:schema:load`.  This takes the schema.rb file and creates new tables based exactly on that file.  Note this will clean your db, so either have a `.dump` file you can import if there is alot of data in development.

Comment: Yes, the records are both saving. I think Rails is smart enough to know that it needs the id of the model to use as the foreign key.

Comment: This is very weird. I've started and restarted my rails server a couple times in the process of testing it and I'm getting the expected behavior. I wonder what's causing the issue?

Comment: Not sure.  I've had collaborative experiences where workflow has gone wrong, and things end up in the schema.rb file from a branch that never made it to production, but it doesn't sound like this is the problem you're experiencing.  Glad a simple reset worked.  Better than dumping the db.

Comment: Updated from my date with the debugger: it turns out a different piece of my code was changing the values. It took a bit to find it. I'm going to give you the check, so future readers will know how to debug the problem.